# Azure Functions Blob Trigger Alternative

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create a bit of serverless architecture and I have a concern about using an Azure Function on a blob trigger.

I have Azure Function 1 that is a Queue Trigger that gets a message to run a request to an API that generates a file and places it in blob storage, the function does not wait for a response. Then I would like to have created an Azure Function 2 that will send that blob/link to a second place. However I was reading about how a blob trigger is not guaranteed to trigger for every blob, I believe "best effort" is the phrase they use in the docs.

My second idea given the "best effort" issue was to have the first function wait for a response and place a message in the queue for a new version of the second function, using a queue trigger instead of a blob trigger.
[image]

I'm wondering if this is worth the trade off of making the Queue Trigger 1 wait for a response, and if the "best effort" risk worth the change. Or if there is a better design out there I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: Use Event Grid, see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-notified-via-azure-event-grid-whenever-azure-blob-is-updated/

Comment: That's exactly what I will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @[peter bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons)

You may use Event Grid instead of the Blob storage trigger  to get notifications whenever something is changed for the following scenarios:
•   Blob storage accounts
•   High scale
•   Minimizing cold-start delay

It has built-in support for events coming from storage blobs and resource groups.
For that we need to create a event grid subscription , need storage account and function app endpoint .

Steps :

1. Login to [Azure portal](https://https/portal.azure.com/) and create an endpoint
2. [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal) a Function App
   So, for creating an endpoint, we will use Function App with trigger type as Azure Event Grid Trigger.
   [image]
3. In the storage account that you have(if not create one) ,create even grid subscription .

[image]

4. To monitor when a file is uploaded to Azure storage , select Event Type as Blob Created.

[image]

5. Add function app details by clicking on  selecting the endpoint.

[image]

Upload file in blob and notice the notifications .

See [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-notified-via-azure-event-grid-whenever-azure-blob-is-updated/) for more details

**Other references:**

1. [Azure Event Grid bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)
2. [Automate resizing uploaded images using Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet%2Cazure-powershell)